# Customize LIA quantifier elimination in Z3

Tags: z3, quantifiers

I'm doing quantifier elimination on LIA using F# and Z3 3.2 API.

Z3 used to have `QUANT_ARITH` configuration which indicates the use of Cooper's method or the Omega test for LIA quantifier elimination. But that option was replaced by `ELIM_QUANTIFIERS` in Z3 2.6 (see [Z3 release notes](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/z3/releasenotes.html)).

I want to ask internally how Z3 3.2 knows which method to use for quantifier elimination? Can users affect the choice of method like `QUANT_ARITH` before?

Furthermore, with the introduction of [strategy specification language](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/leonardo/cp2011.pdf), will Z3 allow us to customize quantifier elimination by extending or combining these methods?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The quantifier elimination module was re-implemented. The new implementation should be faster and correct.
The latest Z3 does not have a implementation of Cooper’s method or Omega test.
You can find more details about the actual quantifier elimination procedure used in Z3 at:
“Linear Quantifier Elimination as an Abstract Decision Procedure, Nikolaj Bjørner, IJCAR 2010”.

Regarding the strategy specification language, we will eventually expose tactics for performing quantifier elimination.
We are currently working on this infrastructure, more news are coming soon.

Comment: I'm still confused. The above paper mentioned several implementations of quantifier elimination which include Cooper's algorithm and Omega test, but I haven't seen those options exposed in Z3. Was the paper written before the quantifier elimination module was re-implemented?

Comment: The old and new implementations coexisted for a short period of time. The old (containing Cooper's method and Omega test) was officially deleted on November of 2010.